# UITableViewController not showing up static content

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

Ok first i know many people have asked this but none of those solution is helping me. I referred to lot of posts in Stackoverflow and everyone did a mistake by adding a data source,
But if you see my controller i have not added any data source. Do i need to pass anything specific?
Please note that my app do use the core data but not this screen.

[image]

Appreciate any help. 
[Newbie IOS developer here]

--Update--
To the negative voter: Will appreciate if you put a reason why this post deserves a negative vote.

Comment: Your outlets aren't connected to the views in your storyboard.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for replying. Its connected. The reason you don't see it on the screenshot because i changed the class name before taking the screenshot for obvious reason. Without connection it wouldn't have compiled also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a Xcode Beta 3 issue. With Beta 4 this is working fine. Crazy apple Betas :)